# How to animate my picture to another point

Tags: html, css

new to HTML and CSS. Could anyone teach me how to animate my picture from my current point to, another location? For example, moving from `"top: 280px: left 600px;"` to `"top:180px; left 500px;"`

Need someone to guide me along, thanks.
Below is my current code:

```css
#robot {
  position: fixed;
  top: 280px;
  left: 600px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('TPHRG floorplan1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
}
```

```html
<img id="robot" src="https://img.favpng.com/20/7/18/clip-art-robot-free-content-image-vector-graphics-png-favpng-pJhfbKDrGy0yuQsKVTrjEu7br.jpg">
```

Comment: [Javascript DOM animated](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_animate.asp) is a simple Javascript animation tutorial, I advise you follow it & adapt it for `top` and `left` rather than `color` and `position` of which is currently changing. SO isn't a tutorial site, if you would like further assistance please provide evidence of what you've tried & errors you're facing so we can assist you in a more technical capacity.

Comment: For animation there should be some trigger point on which animation will work. For example onload, onclick, and many more you have to create that trigger by using javascript or CSS. Now a days CSS alone also using for animation too. Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp andother for javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_animate.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example of an transition between to positions.

The key is to add the `transition` rule to your element (`#robot`), where you set the property you want to animate, the duration of the animation, easing function etc. [See documentation for more examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Note that if you use the `all` keyword in the mentioned rule for shorthand convenience, it is adviced to [specify which property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) you want to animate in the additional `transition-property` rule. This is for performance reasons.

In my example I'm using `:hover` to trigger the animation, but it might as well be when the page loads or when a certain class is added to your element by some JavaScript.

Hope it helps!

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.cat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  transition-property: top, left;
}

.box:hover .cat {
  top: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  Hover me!
  <img class="cat" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="A cat">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for the help. I have use the above guy and your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you can do it by simple using css.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <style>

    #robot {
      position: fixed;
      top: 280px;
      left: 600px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 50px;
      height: 60px;
      -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url('TPHRG floorplan1.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      /* background-position: center; */
      background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
    }
    
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {top: 280px;left:600px;}
  to {top: 180px;left:500px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  from {top: 280px;left:600px;}
  to {top: 180px;left:500px;}
}

  </style>

  <body>

    <img id="robot" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif">

    <?php ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You really helped me alot. 
I still planning to use this code to edit :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qo1mHYstYDU&t=1212s